# How use a char variable in a function to filter on columns in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

How should I use a char variable to filter on a selected column in a written function?

```r
library("data.table")

data = data.table(val = c(NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

dataFun = function(dt, number) {
   colname = paste0("value_", number)
   dt = dt[, (colname) := val + number]
   # the lines below do not work
   dt[is.na(colname), colname] = 0
   dt[colname < 3, colname] = 3
   dt[colname > 5, colname] = 5
   return(dt)
}

data = dataFun(data, 1)
```

Comment: you should use := for all these operations. you can use is.na(get(colname)) to access the column from a string. please see this vignette for more about := https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html

Comment: Thanks. Now it is working. I added fixed code above.

Comment: @nukubiho Move your "fixed code" into an answer below.

Comment: on second look, you might like the `pmin` and `pmax` functions which can make the second two replacements look cleaner; and the nafill/setnafill functions for the first step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the `colname` in `.SDcols` or can `eval`uate after converting to symbol

```
dataFun <- function(dt, number) {
   colname <- paste0("value_", number)
   dt <- dt[, (colname) := val + number]
   colnm <- as.name(colname)
   dt[is.na(eval(colnm)), (colname)  := 0
          ][eval(colnm) < 3, (colname) := 3
           ][eval(colnm) > 5, (colname) := 5][]


 }

dataFun(data, 1)
#   val value_1
#1:  NA       3
#2:   1       3
#3:   2       3
#4:   3       4
#5:   4       5
#6:   5       5
```

Answer (score 1):

A working solution proposed by @MichaelChirico

```r
dataFun = function(dt, number) {
   colname = paste0("value_", number)
   dt = dt[, (colname) := val + number]
   dt[is.na(get(colname)), (colname) := 0]
   dt[get(colname) < 3, (colname) := 3]
   dt[get(colname) > 5, (colname) := 5]
   return(dt)
}
```